# microsoft.dotnet-httprepl is already installed but httprepl command not found in mac

Tags: asp.net, .net

I installed httprepl with command

```
dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.dotnet-httprepl
```

httprepl is listed as installed package with command

```
dotnet tool list -g

Package Id                     Version      Commands
----------------------------------------------------
microsoft.dotnet-httprepl      5.0.2        httprepl
```

but when i run command httprepl it says command not found.

```
httprepl
zsh: command not found: httprepl
```

How can I run httprepl on mac?

Answer (score 8):

In ~/.zshrc write:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.dotnet/tools:$PATH"
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.dotnet-httprepl
Tools directory '/Users/USER/.dotnet/tools' is not currently on the PATH environment variable.
If you are using zsh, you can add it to your profile by running the following command:

```
cat << \EOF >> ~/.zprofile
# Add .NET Core SDK tools
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/USER/.dotnet/tools"
EOF
```

And run `zsh -l` to make it available for current session.

You can only add it to the current session by running the following command:

export PATH="$PATH:/Users/USER/.dotnet/tools"